# View of date field showing time on all day events

Tags: datetime

I have a Event content type with a body and date field from the Date module.

I have a view that shows the events as a block in ascending order, and everything looks cool when I view as an admin. All day events are displayed without a time.

> Event Foo 
>   12/06/2014 to 12/09/2014

However when I look at the block as an anonymous user all day events show up as starting and ending at 2:00

> Event Foo  12/06/2014 - 02:00 to 12/09/2014 - 02:00

How can I get rid of the time?

Edit:
How the Date field looks in the node edit form:
[image: date field from node]

Comment: You need to show us how you've implemented 'all day' events.

Comment: I have turned on the date_all_day module and enabled the collect end date option.  In the node edit forms I've checked the "all day" and "Show End Date" checkboxes in the date field.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue by creating a custom date format and date type.
/admin/config/regional/date-time